# Double scrollbar appearing on homepage

Tags: html, css

I have just updated the theme on my Wordpress site and have noticed that on the homepage a double scrollbar is appearing when on the page. When scrolling one of these scrollbars  it results in a huge amount of white space below the footer.

I have noticed it in Chrome and Safari.

[image]

The site is:

http://millycookbook.com

I have seen people mentioning a fix by adding the following css:

```
body, html {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

This fixes the double scrollbar issue for the homepage but all other pages become unscrollable.

Comment: appears fine on my end? :/

Comment: I added an overflow to the body tag and it appears to have fixed the issue. Thank you for confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following css fixed the issue:

```
body {
   overflow: initial;
}
```